# Database - Entity relationship diagram

Tags: database, attributes, entity, entity-relationship, erd

Presentations:

•   Details of speakers - Speakers, topics, times, contact details, special requirements (if any) e.g. data projection, audio, powerpoint version

•   Details of Chairs (your model should be able to cope with more than one “N” number) for each presentation session, there are chairpersons who chair the presentations; they changeover at refreshment breaks, but we need to know which session each will do; contact details.

With the info above, can I fit both speakers and chairs attributes under one entity called 'Presentation' or should I create two new entities - one for speaker and one for Chairs?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question, it seems like you will want more entities than just those. It depends on if there are any other specifications and data related to each of the entities.

Anyways, here's one possible idea:
Presentations Entity
Persons Entity (name and contact details)
speaker_for relationship (Persons to Presentations)
chairperson_for relationship (Persons to Presentations)

This way someone can speak at many presentations or chair many presentations, and you can easily query that.  Also a person could also speak at one presentation and chair another. You can just have a Speakers entity and a Chairs entity, but they are so similar it seems unnecessary to me.

Like I said, you could adapt this to your liking and conforming to other specs.

Comment: Also the sessions part of your question I wasn't sure about, if there are multiple sessions as part of a larger presentation thing, then you may want a Sessions entity as well.